# CodeMirror overlay that counts parenthesis

Tags: javascript, codemirror, adobe-brackets

**UPDATE:**

I made a fix to the code so it looks like this:

```
var ch;
if (state.inExpression) {
    while ((ch = stream.next()) != null) {
        if (ch == "(") {
            depth++;
        } else if (ch == ")") {
            depth--;
            if (depth === 0) {
                state.inExpression = false;
            }
        }
        return highlightClass;
    }
} else {
    if (stream.match("@if")) {
        state.inExpression = true;
        return highlightClass;
    }
}
```

It works, except if I make a change to the line of code I want highlighted.

I printed to the console and got the following:
[image: screenshot2]

What seems to be happening is before the overlay code is finished parsing, when I make a change to the file the code is interrupted and restarted. The problem is that the `depth` counter never was reset so the parentheses count gets messed up.

How can I make sure my loop will run uninterrupted? Or is there a different solution?

---

**Original Question:**
I am trying to write a CodeMirror Overlay to highlight Laravel syntax. An example of syntax to be highlighted would be `@if (foo(bar))`. The highlighting should start at the `@` and end after the last `)`, thus it is necessary to count parenthesis.

The following is the code I wrote to achieve this, but it is not working properly.

```
var ch;
if (state.inExpression) {
    while ((ch = stream.next()) != null) {
        if (ch == "(") {
            depth++;
            return highlightClass;
        } else if (ch == ")") {
            depth--;
            if (depth === 0) {
                state.inExpression = false;
                return highlightClass;
            }
        }
    } 
} else {
    if (stream.match("@if")) {
       state.inExpression = true;
       return highlightClass;
    }
}
```

The results are hard to describe, so just take a look at this screenshot:
[image: screenshot1]

But it seems that my code also messes up the 'matching bracket' feature that is built in.

I think for some reason I am not properly exiting the `state.inExpression`.

Any ideas?